# How can I generate a DEB from an installed package?

Tags: debian, apt

I've done this in the past before but I can't remember how. I'd like to take an installed package on one machine, create an installable deb from it, then send that deb over to another machine. How can I generate the deb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`dpkg-repack`](http://packages.debian.org/dpkg-repack)

Comment: Does this break a record for the shortest legal answer ever given on SE?

Comment: @TKKocheran No: 55>30

Comment: Run a url shortener and you'd be home free.